# Python: high cpu scrapy how to debug

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I'm trying to debug my cpu usage. I tried several things already:

- add `sleep(0.1)` to Pipelines
- disabling Pipelines
- Using Scrapyd with job persistance (JOBDIR paramater to save data to the disk instead of keeping it in memory), but I guess this only counts for RAM.
- set the amount of jobs per cpu with settings like below.

scrapy.cfg:

```
[scrapyd]    
max_proc = 0    
max_proc_per_cpu = 2
```

Which didn't help either. These are my stats when running a spider:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 3221 scrapy    20   0  836724  75568   8432 R 40.5  7.4   1:04.31 python
 3231 scrapy    20   0  836724  75568   8432 S  1.0  7.4   0:01.40 python
 3234 scrapy    20   0  836724  75568   8432 S  1.0  7.4   0:01.42 python
 3235 scrapy    20   0  836724  75568   8432 S  1.0  7.4   0:01.44 python
 3228 scrapy    20   0  836724  75568   8432 S  0.7  7.4   0:01.43 python
```

Anyone who can help? I noticed that if I add the `sleep(0.1)` I don't see a peak in the CPU usage charts, but a constant CPU usage of around 50% for several minutes. Because the spider takes longer to finish, obviously. But I think it's strange it constantly uses exactly 50% cpu during the task. When more scrapers are running at the same time, the cpu will go over the 70%, most of the time it uses almost 100% cpu.

Comment: It is not the solution for the high cpu consumption, but have you considered starting scrapyd with Nice (assuming you are on Linux)? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, you can allocate a certain amount of CPU time to the scrapy tasks, but it will slow down the process? In that case it wouldn't be a good solution for me. The spiders need to run fast, because the amount of spiders grow each week and most of them are running each 30 minutes. So if necessary we can scale up the servers, but now it seems we just use too much CPU. I mean, one scraper using constantly 50% cpu, that doesn't seem right.

Comment: You can set how nice the Scrapy task must be to other tasks. Nice --> all other processes coming first. Not nice --> Scrapyd comes first. So if a webserver also wants cpu time you can control which comes first.

Comment: This CPU usage is nothing out of the ordinary. Is the CPU multi-core? If so, this is only 50% of a single core. Even if it's 100% of a single core, that's still regular. Because it takes what it can take, specially if your concurrent requests is high, why not?